# How can I play a song with mpc.el without adding it to the playlist first?

Tags: music-player

Whenever I try to play a new song in mpc.el.

```
mpc-songs-jump-to: This song is not in the playlist
```

I have to mpc-playlist-add the song before I can play it.

Why is that? This is not the behavior of ncmpcpp, so why is it different here?

Answer (score 0):

You can just do;)

```
mpc-play-at-point
```